# datetimepicker can't change to DD/MM/YY - ADMIN LTE

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetimepicker, bootstrap-datetimepicker, adminlte

I've been working with a code and it's all fine, but I cant change the data format. Also, when I deleted the "   $('#reservationdate').datetimepicker({" code
it still works and it shouldn't, so I don't know where to start. I'm using the same example in adminLTE with no help.

What I'm getting: "08/21/2020 4:32 PM"

when i send the $_POST i'm getting "`\/`" between the dates:

```
08\/26\/2020 5:20 PM
```

What I want: "21/08/2020"

Extra: I'm using links in href for datetimepicker because I couldn't find the link rel or the script location in the "pages/forms/advance.html" file.

**Header:**

```
<!-- Font Awesome -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="plugins/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css">
  <!-- Ionicons -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.ionicframework.com/ionicons/2.0.1/css/ionicons.min.css">
  <!-- overlayScrollbars -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/adminlte.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/sweetalert2.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/admin.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="plugins/datatables-bs4/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="plugins/datatables-responsive/css/responsive.bootstrap4.min.css">


  <!-- daterange picker -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="plugins/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.css">
  <!-- iCheck for checkboxes and radio inputs -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="plugins/icheck-bootstrap/icheck-bootstrap.min.css">
  <!-- Bootstrap Color Picker -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="plugins/bootstrap-colorpicker/css/bootstrap-colorpicker.min.css">
  <!-- Tempusdominus Bbootstrap 4 -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="plugins/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4/css/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4.min.css">
  <!-- Select2 -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="plugins/select2/css/select2.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="plugins/select2-bootstrap4-theme/select2-bootstrap4.min.css">
  <!-- Bootstrap4 Duallistbox -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="plugins/bootstrap4-duallistbox/bootstrap-duallistbox.min.css">
  <!-- Google Font: Source Sans Pro -->
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:300,400,400i,700" rel="stylesheet">
```

**Footer:**

```
<!-- jQuery -->
<script src="plugins/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Bootstrap 4 -->
<script src="plugins/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<!-- DataTables -->
<script src="plugins/datatables/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="plugins/datatables-bs4/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>
<script src="plugins/datatables-responsive/js/dataTables.responsive.min.js"></script>
<script src="plugins/datatables-responsive/js/responsive.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>
<!-- AdminLTE App -->
<script src="js/adminlte.min.js"></script>



<!-- Select2 -->
<script src="plugins/select2/js/select2.full.min.js"></script>
<!-- Bootstrap4 Duallistbox -->
<script src="plugins/bootstrap4-duallistbox/jquery.bootstrap-duallistbox.min.js"></script>
<!-- InputMask -->
<script src="plugins/moment/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="plugins/inputmask/min/jquery.inputmask.bundle.min.js"></script>
<!-- date-range-picker -->
<script src="plugins/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.js"></script>
<!-- bootstrap color picker -->
<script src="plugins/bootstrap-colorpicker/js/bootstrap-colorpicker.min.js"></script>
<!-- Tempusdominus Bootstrap 4 -->
<script src="plugins/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4/js/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4.min.js"></script>
<!-- Bootstrap Switch -->
<script src="plugins/bootstrap-switch/js/bootstrap-switch.min.js"></script>
```

**app.js:** (Even if i delete this code it will work)

```
$('#reservationdate').datetimepicker({
      format: 'dd/mm/yyyy'
   });
```

Comment: `dd` is Su, Mo, Tu, We, etc. and `mm` and `yyyy` are invalid. Consult the [momentjs format docs](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/) as mentioned by the [bootstrap-datetimepicker](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Options/) docs.

Comment: You will also need to decide whether you are going to use [bootstrap-datetimepicker](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/) or [Tempus Dominus](https://tempusdominus.github.io/bootstrap-4/Options/), as you have included both of them, and naturally they are not compatible.

Comment: I'm using the adminLTE, but it says that without tempus Dominus library I can't use it... i just want it to be date without time and change the format but it wont let me

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in the class of the input, because it was "datetimepicker", but it had to be "datepicker" or "timepicker". From that point I could change the format.

**How it was:**

```
 <input type="date" class="form-control datetimepicker-input" data-target="#reservationdate" name="fecha_evento"/>
```

**How it wa resolved:**

```
 <input type="date" class="form-control datepicker-input" data-target="#reservationdate" name="fecha_evento"/>
```

pd. The libraries didn't got problems as they showed to be compatible.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe `mm` mean minute?

You can try using MM/YYYY?

Comment: Please phrase this as an explained conditional answer, in order to avoid the impression of asking a clarification question instead of answering (for which a comment should be used instead of an answer, compare https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead ). For example like "If your problem is ... then the solution is to .... because .... ."